# What was the first published map for an adventure?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, history-of-gaming, maps

What is the first officially published dungeon map from D&D?

I believe there was no dungeon map in the first published book, but I'd like to know what the first map was that was published.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 1974 in *The Underworld and Wilderness Adventures*

While the 1975 *Blackmoor* supplement had an actual adventure with a keyed map and a story line, the first published dungeon map can be found a year earlier in [*The Underworld and Wilderness Adventures*](https://i.4pcdn.org/tg/1456066509204.pdf), published in 1974. On page 3 is a sample cross section of multiple dungeon levels and the ways they can be linked. On page 4 is sample dungeon level map, and a key for eight numbered encounter areas is on page 5. Since the map has a key with encounters, it is technically a playable dungeon adventure, even though there's no real story around it and the main idea is to demonstrate how to lay out a dungeon level and give ideas for tricks and traps.

*The Underworld and Wilderness Adventures* was one of the three books in the original D&D boxed set, the earliest D&D product. You won’t find any D&D maps published earlier than this.

Answer (score 9):

The oldest map I've been able to locate is from *Dungeons & Dragons Supplement II: Blackmoor*, which contains maps of the original version of the Temple of the Frog. It's [DriveThruRPG listing](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/17172/ODD-Supplement-II-Blackmoor-0e) states it was originally printed "**around April 1975**"

A scan of the map from a later printing can be seen in [this store listing](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/tsr-dungeons-dragons-supplement-ii-1876973204).

Comment: That was the first 'published adventure' and included a map.  The original game, book III, has a sample a sample dungeon.